# Identifying the files older than x-months by the filename only and deleting them

Tags: bash, shell, date, sh

I have 4 different files with different fileName.date formats, having a date embedded as part of the name. I want to identify the files older than 3 months based on their name only because the files would be edited/changed later as well. I want to create a shell script and run it as a cron.
Here below are the file under the same directory:

1. fileone.log.2018-03-23
2. file_two_2018-03-23.log
3. filethree.log.2018-03-23
4. file_four_file_four_2018-03-23.log

I have checked the existing example but have not found what I am actually looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working on the premise that you mean 90 days - if you need specifically months, we can check that too, but it's different logic.

> #### here's some code you could work from -
>
> (you said you don't want to work from a list, so I edited to use the current directory.)

```
$: cat chkDates
# while read f # replaced with -
for f in *[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]*
do # first get the epoch timestamp of the file based on the sate string embedded in the name
   filedate=$(
      date +%s -d $(
         echo $f | sed -E 's/.*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*/\1/'
      ) # this returns the date substring
   )    # this converts it to an epoch integer of seconds since 1/1/70
   # now see if it's > 90 days ( you said 3 months. if you need *months* we have to do some more...)
   daysOld=$(( ( $(date +%s) - $filedate ) / 86400 )) # this should give you an integer result, btw
   if (( 90 < $daysOld ))
   then echo $f is old
   else echo $f is not
   fi
done # < listOfFileNames # not reading list now
```

You can pass `date` a date to report, and a format to present it.

> sed pattern explanation

Note the `sed -E 's/.*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*/\1/'` command. This assumes the date format will be consistently `YYYY-MM-DD`, and does no validations of reasonableness. It will happily accept any 4 digits, then 2, then 2, delimited by dashes.

`-E` uses expanded regexes, so parens `()` can denote values to be remembered, without needing `\`'s. `.` means any character, and `*` means any number (including zero) of the previous pattern, so `.*` means zero or more characters, eating up all the line before the date. `[0-9]` means any digit. `{x,y}` sets a minimum(x) and maximum(y) number of consecutive matches - with only one value `{4}` means only exactly 4 of the previous pattern will do. So, `'.*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*'` means ignore as many characters as you can until seeing 4 digits, then a dash, 2 digits, then a dash, then 2 digits; remember that pattern (the `()`'s), then ignore any characters behind it.

In a substitution, `\1` means the first remembered match, so

```
sed -E 's/.*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*/\1/'
```

means find and remember the date pattern in the filenames, and replace the whole name with just that part in the output. This assumes the date will be present - on a filename where there is no date, the pattern will not match, and the whole filename will be returned, so be careful with that.

> (hope that helped.)

By isolating the date string from the filenames with `sed` (your examples were format-consistent, so I used that) we pass it in and ask for the UNIX Epoch timestamp of that date string using `date +%s -d $(...)`, to represent the file with a math-handy number.

Subtract that from the current date in the same format, you get the approximate age of the file in seconds. Divide *that* by the number of seconds in a day and you get days old. The file date will default to midnight, but the math will drop fractions, so it sorts out.

> #### here's the file list I made, working from your examples

```
$: cat listOfFileNames
fileone.log.2018-03-23
fileone.log.2018-09-23
file_two_2018-03-23.log
file_two_2018-08-23.log
filethree.log.2018-03-23
filethree.log.2018-10-02
file_four_file_four_2018-03-23.log
file_four_file_four_2019-03-23.log
```

I added a file for each that would be within the 90 days as of this posting - including one that is "post-dated", which can easily happen with this sort of thing.

> #### Here's the output.

```
$: ./chkDates
fileone.log.2018-03-23 is old
fileone.log.2018-09-23 is not
file_two_2018-03-23.log is old
file_two_2018-08-23.log is not
filethree.log.2018-03-23 is old
filethree.log.2018-10-02 is not
file_four_file_four_2018-03-23.log is old
file_four_file_four_2019-03-23.log is not
```

That what you had in mind?

> #### An alternate pure-bash way to get just the date string

(You still need `date` to convert to the epoch seconds...)

instead of

```
   filedate=$(
      date +%s -d $(
         echo $f | sed -E 's/.*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*/\1/'
      ) # this returns the date substring
   )    # this converts it to an epoch integer of seconds since 1/1/70
```

which doesn't seem to be working for you, try this:

```
tmp=${f%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]*} # unwanted prefix
d=${f#$tmp}                                          # prefix removed
tmp=${f#*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]} # unwanted suffix
filedate=${d%$tmp}                                   # suffix removed
filedate=$( date +%s --date=$filedate )              # epoch time
```

This is hard to read, but doesn't have to spawn as many subprocesses to get the work done. :)

If that doesn't work, then I'm suspicious of your version of `date`. Mine:

```
$: date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.26
```

Comment: Looks like I threw this together while you were updating yours, lol. Great minds think alike...and apparently so do we? >:oD

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I tried the same you suggested and I got the output and also below error: date: option requires an argument -- 'd'
Try 'date --help' for more information.
./chkDates.sh: line 9: ( 1540483671 -  ) / 86400 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is ") / 86400 ").

What I don't want in this way is it takes all the list of the files names from the file 'listOfFileNames' instead of reading file names from the directory. 
I have the directory with some files to be deleted (file-name-having -date-in-them) and some should not be touched.

Comment: Check to make sure your code has `-d` and not just `d`.  Your version might require `--date=$(...)`. Also, I just used the list as an example - I assume you will edit the code to fit whatever you are doing.

Comment: I am very happy that it worked in one shot for me but I am still wondering how that sed command works for all the different type of file names having date in it. I am a just a begineer who is trying to learn and understand shell scripts.

Comment: Will elaborate.

Comment: I have copied the same script which you have given. it has -d at line no:4. Anything else I need to check, please let me know

Comment: Sorry, Been away for a while. 
Worked like a flash. Thanks very much. And the explanation about the sed command is more of my kind but still understood some part of it. Going to start using this, fingers crossed that it works for all irrespective of leap years, months having 30,31 days. Especially when the year will change to 2019. I know that I am asking silly questions but as mentioned I am just a beginner in a shell script. This place is a good platform to learn.

Comment: Thanks @PaulHodges

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

**Simple Version:**

Method for using the date inside of the file's name :

```
typeset stamp=$(date --date="90 day ago" +%s)
for file in /directory/*.log; do
        fdate="$(echo "$file" | sed 's/[^0-9-]*//g')"
        fstamp=$(date -d "${fdate} 00:00:00"  +"%s")
        if [ ${fstamp} -le ${stamp} ] ; then
                echo "${file} : ${fdate} (${fstamp})"   
        fi
done
```

**A More Complete Version**:

This version will look at all files, if it fails to make a date value from the file it moves on.

```
typeset stamp=$(date --date="90 day ago" +%s)
for file in /tmp/* ; do
        fdate="$(echo "$file" | sed 's/[^0-9-]*//g')"
        fstamp=$(date -d "${fdate} 00:00:00"  +"%s" 2> /dev/null)
        [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && continue
        if [ ${fstamp} -le ${stamp} ] ; then
                echo "${file} : ${fdate} (${fstamp})"   
        fi
done
```

output:

```
/tmp/file_2016-05-23.log : 2016-05-23 (1463976000)
/tmp/file_2017-05-23.log : 2017-05-23 (1495512000)
/tmp/file_2018-05-23.log : 2018-05-23 (1527048000)
/tmp/file_2018-06-23.log : 2018-06-23 (1529726400)
/tmp/file_2018-07-23.log : 2018-07-23 (1532318400)
```

in this example the following were ignored :

```
/tmp/file_2018-08-23.log : 2018-08-23 (1534996800)
/tmp/file_2018-10-18.log : 2018-10-18 (1539835200)
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, but I am looking to find older files based on the date which will be present as part of the file name as mentioned above in my question. -mtime will not work for me because if 30 day old file is edited today then if we do -mtime +30 then it will not give this file.